# How to delete last line of a multiline command output in powershell

Tags: powershell

How can I delete the last line of a command output with PowerShell?

The output looks like this:

```
[{"Event":{"EventData":{"CommandLine":"nslookup  test2.com","MandatoryLabel":"S-1-16-12288","NewProcessId":"0x2094","NewProcessName":"C:\\Windows\\System32\\nslookup.exe","ParentProcessName":"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe","ProcessId":"0x868","SubjectDomainName":"RM-PC","SubjectLogonId":"0x1ddc2c","SubjectUserName":"richa","SubjectUserSid":"S-1-5-21-1405040689-326705664-3657760936-1001","TargetDomainName":"-","TargetLogonId":"0x0","TargetUserName":"-","TargetUserSid":"S-1-0-0","TokenElevationType":"%%1937"},"System":{"Channel":"Security","Computer":"RM-PC","Correlation":null,"EventID":4688,"EventRecordID":20413251,"Execution_attributes":{"ProcessID":4,"ThreadID":7320},"Keywords":"0x8020000000000000","Level":0,"Opcode":0,"Provider_attributes":{"Guid":"54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D","Name":"Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing"},"Security":null,"Task":13312,"TimeCreated_attributes":{"SystemTime":"2022-10-12T12:11:17.996728Z"},"Version":2}},"Event_attributes":{"xmlns":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"}}]
[+] Found 2 hits
```

I want to delete the last line "[+] Found **x** hits" and it is worth to mention, that the number of hits is dynamic.

I have tried this, but didn't work:

```
$linecounter = 0
$output=.\command.exe

while($linecounter -le 1)  
{  
    foreach ($line in $output){
      $linecounter=$linecounter+1
      Write-Host $line

    }
}
```

What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Select-Object` cmdlet with the `-SkipLast` parameter to skip the last item in a stream of output:

```
$output = .\command.exe |Select-Object -SkipLast 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helfpul answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74041976/45375) is unquestionably the **best solution for** removing one (or more) input objects (lines) from ***streaming* input**:

- That is, PowerShell relays the (stdout) output from your `.\command.exe` *line by line*, as each line becomes available, and [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) `-SkipLast 1` then passes all but the last one through.

---

For ***arrays (collections) already in memory*, *array slicing* is the more efficient alternative** (though with smallish arrays that likely won't matter), although its syntax isn't as convenient as it could be, as of PowerShell 7.2.x, because it currently **requires an explicit reference to the array's max. index**:

```
# A 5-element sample array.
$output = 'line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4', 'line 5'

# Use array slicing to remove the last element.
# Note: Of necessity returns a *new* array, with the last element removed
$output[0..($output.Count-1 - 1)] # $output.Count-1 is the max. index
```

While PowerShell's array (collection) indexing (`[...]`) is very flexible and you can refer to *individual* elements relative to the *end* of the array with negative numbers (e.g, `(1, 2, 3)[-1]` yields `3`), PowerShell as of 7.2.x **unfortunately lacks the ability to specify *from-the-end* indices as part of element *ranges***, the way that other languages such as Python support:

- Something like `(1, 2, 3)[0..-1]` does *not* return `1, 2` as one might expect, because `..`, the general-purpose [range operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-), simply creates the following (temporary) array strictly based on its *literal* numeric endpoint, whose elements then serve as indices into the enclosing array: `0, -1`; thus, `(1, 2, 3)[0..-1]` is the equivalent of `(1, 2, 3)[0, -1]`(!) and therefore returns `1, 3`
- ***New syntax* would have to be introduced** to allow range endpoints to be expressed relative to the *end* of an array, as proposed in [GitHub issue #7940](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7940).

  - Following the model of C#, `^` could be used to refer to the end of an array in `..` ranges; e.g.:

    ```
    # WISHFUL THINKING as of PowerShell 7.2.x
    (1, 2, 3)[0..^1] # -> 1, 2
    ```